# Код не компилируется, выдавай ошибку "Multiple definitions of "

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, компиляция

Я пишу игру "Сокобан". Код, который есть на данный момент, ниже, а проблема заключается в том, что этот код не компилируется, выдавай такую ошибку:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `levels'
game.o:game.cpp:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
main.o:main.cpp:(.bss+0x14): multiple definition of `Game::level'
game.o:game.cpp:(.bss+0x14): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Файл **main.cpp** выглядит так:

```
#include "game.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char **argw)
{
   Game::start(argc, argw);
   return 0;
}
```

**game.h**

```
#ifndef _Game
#define _Game

#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "level.h"
#include "levels.h"
#include "object.h"

class Game
{
private:
  static Object player;
  static Level* level;

  static int width;
  static int height;

  static int levelNum;

  static void setup();
  static void draw();
  static void keys();
  static void resize(int w, int h);

public:
  static void start(int argc, char **argw);
};

Level *Game::level;

#endif
```

**level.h**

```
#ifndef _Level
#define _Level

#include <vector>
#include <GL\glut.h>
#include <list>
#include "object.h"

using std::vector;
using std::list;

class Level
{
private:
  vector<Object> objects;

  int px;
  int py;

public:
  Level(list<list<int> > room);
  Level();

  void operator=(Level other)
  {
    objects = other.objects;
  }

  int getPx(){return px;}
  int getPy(){return py;}

  void draw();
};

#endif
```

**object.h**

```
#ifndef _Object
#define _Object

#include "square.h"

enum Dir {Up, Rigth, Down, Left};

enum Type {
            Block  = 0b10000, // 16
            Player = 0b01000, // 8
            Box    = 0b00100, // 4
            Aim    = 0b00010, // 2
            Empty  = 0b00001, // 1
           };

#define isEmpty(t) (t & 1)

#define isAim(t) (t>>1 & 1)

#define isBox(t) (t>>2 & 1)

#define isPlayer(t) (t>>3 & 1)

class Object: public Square
{
private:
  Type type;

public:
  void setX(int x_){x = x_;}
  void setY(int y_){y = y_;}

  void move(Dir dir);

  Object(int x_, int y_, int w, int h, Type t) : Square(x, y, w, h)
  {
    type = t;
  }
};

#endif
```

**square.h**

```
#ifndef _Square
#define _Square

class Square
{
protected:
  int x;
  int y;

  int width;
  int height;

public:
  int getX(){return x;}
  int getY(){return y;}

  int getWidth(){return width;}
  int getHeight(){return height;}

  Square(int x_, int y_, int w, int h)
  {
    x = x_;
    y = y_;

    width = w;
    height = h;
  }
};

#endif
```

**levels.h**

```
#ifndef _Square
#define _Square

class Square
{
protected:
  int x;
  int y;

  int width;
  int height;

public:
  int getX(){return x;}
  int getY(){return y;}

  int getWidth(){return width;}
  int getHeight(){return height;}

  Square(int x_, int y_, int w, int h)
  {
    x = x_;
    y = y_;

    width = w;
    height = h;
  }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Очень странно сработал тэг `code`.

Comment: А нет тега code.

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка в том, что `levels.h` использует `#ifndef _Square`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> multiple definition of `Game::level'

Само собой:

```
Level *Game::level;
```

Каждый раз, когда подключаете `game.h`, определяется эта переменная. Выносите все данные в *.cpp, а не в инклуды.